# MySQL Opening Hours

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to query the following opening hours:

```
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
| openDay | openTime | closeDay | closeTime |
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
|       0 | 1800     |        1 |  400      |
|       1 | 1800     |        2 |  400      |
|       2 | 1800     |        3 |  400      |
|       3 | 1800     |        4 |  400      |
|       4 | 1800     |        5 |  400      |
|       5 | 1800     |        6 |  400      |
|       6 | 1800     |        0 |  400      |
+---------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Give a day of the week (0...6) I want to determine if a place is currently open. If all places opened and closed on the same day I could simply run something like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM opening_hrs
WHERE (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) >= openTime) 
AND (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) <= closeTime)
AND openDay = 1
```

However if using openDay = 1 the place is technically open from 0-400 and 1800-2400. How can I alter the query to account for these multiple times periods?

The table format is a production table so changing the format doesn't work in this particular scenario (though would ease the problem a lot).

Answer (score 1):

If you can not modify the table, then you could use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM opening_hrs
WHERE (((100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) >= openTime) 
        AND (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) <= closeTime + 2400*(closeDay-openDay)))
       OR 
       ((100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) >= openTime - 2400*(closeDay-openDay)) 
        AND (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) <= closeTime )))
AND openDay = 1
```

---

If you can modify the table to look like this:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
|     day | openTime | closeTime |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|       0 | 1800     |  2400     |
|       1 | 1800     |  2400     |
|       2 | 1800     |  2400     |
|       3 | 1800     |  2400     |
|       4 | 1800     |  2400     |
|       5 | 1800     |  2400     |
|       6 | 1800     |  2400     |
|       0 |    0     |   400     |
|       1 |    0     |   400     |
|       2 |    0     |   400     |
|       3 |    0     |   400     |
|       4 |    0     |   400     |
|       5 |    0     |   400     |
|       6 |    0     |   400     |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

then you could perform the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM opening_hrs
WHERE (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) >= openTime) 
AND (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) <= closeTime)
AND day = 1
```

Note that there is no more openDay and closeDay;  just a `day` column.
Note also that the `openTime` is always less than the `closeTime`, so the inequalities in the query can work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using a production table produced by others so I am limited in its format.

Answer (score 0):

when testing the closing time, you could compare to

```
AND (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) < closeTime + 2400*(closeDay - openDay))
```

the above would treat hour 0400 as 2800, which is numerically greater than any time today

to test the period 0000-0400, you can check the current time falls inside the previous day's open hours that straddle the day boundary, something like

```
OR (100*HOUR(NOW())+MINUTE(NOW()) <
        (SELECT MIN(closeTime) FROM opening_hrs
          WHERE closeDay = 1 AND openTime > closeTime)
)
```

Edit: if > vs >= does not matter, you could combine the range tests into a single `(hours00+minutes) between openTime and closeTime`