# MySQL DateTime calculations for opening hours

Tags: mysql, datetime

So we have the following MySQL table with opening hours:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| Id   | StartTime           | EndTime             | ClubId |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|    1 | 1970-01-04 20:00:00 | 1970-01-05 01:00:00 |  17424 |
|    2 | 1970-01-05 20:00:00 | 1970-01-06 01:00:00 |  17424 |
|    3 | 1970-01-06 20:00:00 | 1970-01-07 05:00:00 |  17424 |
|    4 | 1970-01-07 20:00:00 | 1970-01-01 05:00:00 |  17424 |
|    5 | 1970-01-01 22:00:00 | 1970-01-02 05:00:00 |  17426 |
|    6 | 1970-01-04 22:00:00 | 1970-01-05 05:00:00 |  17426 |
|    7 | 1970-01-05 22:00:00 | 1970-01-06 05:00:00 |  17426 |
|    8 | 1970-01-06 22:00:00 | 1970-01-07 05:00:00 |  17426 |
|    9 | 1970-01-07 22:00:00 | 1970-01-01 05:00:00 |  17426 |
|   10 | 1970-01-01 20:00:00 | 1970-01-02 04:00:00 |  17427 |
|   11 | 1970-01-03 20:00:00 | 1970-01-04 05:00:00 |  17427 |
|   12 | 1970-01-04 20:00:00 | 1970-01-05 05:00:00 |  17427 |
|   13 | 1970-01-05 20:00:00 | 1970-01-06 05:00:00 |  17427 |
|   14 | 1970-01-02 18:00:00 | 1970-01-03 03:00:00 |  17428 |

...
```

where `StartTime` is when the business opens and `EndTime` when it closes. We don't care about the year and month of the dates but the **day represents the day of the week** (even though it may not match the historical data. `1970-01-01` may have been a Thursday, but as we don't care about year and month we don't care about the historical context either. We simply defined that the day `01` represents a Sunday) and that's all we care about. So after `1970-01-07` (Saturday) comes `1970-01-01` (Sunday). The times are just what you'd expect from opening hours.

Let's take a look at where Id = 1 for example:
StartTime `1970-01-04 20:00:00` and EndTime `1970-01-05 01:00:00` means that this club opens on `Wednesday 8 PM` and closes on `Thursday 1 AM`.

What we need to do (and what's giving us trouble) is to filter these entries to only show businesses that are currently **open**. I tried using the `INBETWEEN` keyword but entries like `Id = 9` where the day of the week goes from 7 (Saturday) to 1 (Sunday) are giving me trouble.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Has anyone any experience with stuff like this and has an idea on how to put this into a MySQL query?
I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278741/mysql-opening-hours) however they are not using datetime objects. If it can't be avoided we could alter the tables and use the proposed solution from the question above but we would prefer using the `DATETIME` datatype (if possible).

Comment: I don't get it. January 1st, 1970 was a Thursday. Now you say it should be considered as Sunday?

Comment: Good point I guess I didn't really explain our internal 'misuse' of the datetime datatype. updated the question. But as we are only interested in storing the day of the week and the time we defined `1970-01-01` to be a Sunday (even though it's not historically accurate)

Comment: if i understand correctly you mean that each +7 days starting from 1970-01-01 is to be considered  closed  (as sunday) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient option probably is to transform the current date/time to a value that is consistent with your representation of dates in the table. Then you can do direct filtering.

As I understand your question, that would be:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now() + interval 3 day) % (60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
```

The logic is to use modulo to project the current date/time as the equivalent date in the first week of epoch. Additional logic is needed to remap the January 1st, 1970 as a Sunday (while in reality it was a Thursday): that's what the `+ interval 3 day` does.

We can test that the mapping works correctly like so:

```
select now(), 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now() + interval 3 day) % (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) ts_now
```

Yields:

```
now()               | ts_now             
:------------------ | :------------------
2020-10-23 09:52:59 | 1970-01-05 10:52:59
```

Then you can then put that in the `where` clause of a query. Using a subquery is handy to avoid repeating the expression:

```
select t.clubid
from mytable t
inner join (select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now() + interval 3 day) % (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) ts_now) x
where t.starttime >= x.ts_now and t.endtime < x.ts_now
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it mate, this got me on the right track. However I had to use `+ interval 4 day` (Sunday to Thursday are 4 days :D) and the "larger than" / "less than" operators have to be the other way around ;)
So the resulting query that worked is
`select oh.* from openinghours oh inner join (select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now() + interval 4 day) % (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)) ts_now) x where oh.starttime <= x.ts_now and oh.endtime >= x.ts_now;`